# Big query scheduled query custom timing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to schedule a query on BigQuery **form Monday to Saturday**, **every 15 minutes from 04:00 to 21:00**.
That's my try:

```
every mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat every 15 minutes from 04:00 to 21:00
```

I'm sure that this part: "every 15 minutes from 04:00 to 21:00" is working, need to add the part related to days of the week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem and not solved yet. There is no reference in doc for scheduling by weekday and by time in the same custom scheduling rule. This is not possible, I guess.
As said before, doc has the note:

> Important considerations for schedule:
>
> You must decide if you want to use either a sub-daily interval or a
> custom interval. You cannot mix and use elements from the various
> interval types. The following is an example of an invalid schedule
> definition: schedule: every 6 hours mon,wed,fri.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
read [set_up_scheduled_queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#set_up_scheduled_queries)

> Important considerations for schedule:
>
> 1.You must decide if you want to use either a sub-daily interval or a custom interval. You cannot mix and use elements from the various
> interval types. The following is an example of an invalid schedule
> definition: `schedule: every 6 hours mon,wed,fri`
>
> 2.Only a single instance of a job should run at any time. The Cron service is designed to provide "at least once" delivery; that is, if a
> job is scheduled, App Engine sends the job request at least one time.
> In some rare circumstances, it is possible for multiple instances of
> the same job to be requested, therefore, your request handler should
> be idempotent, and your code should ensure that there are no harmful
> side-effects if this occurs.

based on the above you have two option

1st

`schedule: every 15 minutes`

means every seven days of every week

or 2nd

`schedule: every mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat 04:00`

not sure about if it takes the interval if it is then try

`schedule: every mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat 04:00 to 21:00`

once in every given day

also as you said that

`every 15 minutes from 04:00 to 21:00`

so this also

Comment: I get this error message: "Error updating scheduled query: The specified schedule is invalid: [every 15 minutes from 04:00 to 21:00 every mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat]"

Comment: Did you tried the solution you are suggesting? I keep getting the same error with the updated version as well

Comment: no i did not i am answering based on the documentation and other articles as i am going through them, so far i did not find any thing straight in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#set_up_scheduled_queries) for this type of task ,that is why i am just posting the possible approach .i will  update the answer if i get any better.